# iMac G5 works very loudly. How to fix it?

Tags: imac, g5

I only run Safari with maximum 3-5 tabs opened and the machine makes noise like a vacuum cleaner making it very hard to work on.
Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If you think that the fans are running at a higher speed that they should, you could try [reseting the SMU](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1767).

If the issue is just with the sound being too loud, then the best option would be to [open the computer](http://www.ifixit.com/Device/iMac_G5) and clean the dust, mainly from the fans and the ventilation-related. Even more, overheat could have caused the fans to *slightly* bend, making some *annoying* noises. If that is the case, the only option would be to replace it with a new one. Replacing the thermal grease could be helpful too, if you've got overheating issues.